# use the numpy.delete(...) delete array [('aa',1),('bb',2)],After delete the first column, the second column becomes a string

Tags: python, numpy

use the numpy.delete(...) delete array example for **[('aa',1),('bb',2)]**,After delete the first column, the second column become a string,example for **[('1'),('2')]**.but I want the second column to keep the original int type,how to do this.thanks for help.

Comment: Check the array dtype before `delete`.  Oh, and make sure you are checking the array, not a list of lists.  If you give `np.delete` a list of lists, it will first create an array from that.  `np.delete` returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

A list 'delete':

```
In [92]: alist = [('aa',1),('bb',2)]                                                                         
In [93]: [(row[1],) for row in alist]                                                                        
Out[93]: [(1,), (2,)]
```

If we make an array from this list, we get a string dtype:

```
In [94]: np.array(alist)                                                                                     
Out[94]: 
array([['aa', '1'],
       ['bb', '2']], dtype='<U2')
In [95]: np.delete(_, 0, 1)                                                                                  
Out[95]: 
array([['1'],
       ['2']], dtype='<U2')
```